# ssh connection refuse after ssd_config edit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, connection

Yesterday on a hosted virtual server (ubuntu) I edited the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** with the following row:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

After that I restarted the sshd with the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Today when I tried to connect to the server (port 22), I got a "**connection refused**" message.

I asked the server host company to reboot it, and now I'm waiting for that, but I'm afraid it won't solve the problem!

Any suggestion what i can do? (i'm not a pro linux user)

EDIT:

I know that it was a mistake and the main question is how i can reach the (remote) server to delete that row?

Comment: Login via the remote administration console your hosting provider hopefully offers.

Comment: which ssh server are you using? can you share sshd_config?

Comment: @arkascha i will ask them! thanks

Comment: @RahulRDhobi i don't know what i'm using :(. i can't share it because i can't reach the server right now.

Comment: Do you have access of telnet??

Comment: @RahulRDhobi tried it and unfortunatley i've got the same "connection refused" response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Login via the remote administration console your hosting provider hopefully offers. –  arkascha Feb 7 at 10:11

This comment was the most helpful and luckily the hosting provider has remote admin console, so i can revert the mistake i've been made!

Answer (score 1):

I think the ServerAlive property cannot be used in the sshd_config. As a result your SSH daemon probably crashed because of errors in your config. Change that to the CLientInterval property.

[According to this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-ssh-server-connection-drops-out-after-few-or-n-minutes-of-inactivity.html) on the server side the property "ClientAliveInterval" can be adjusted to make sure the connection is closed less often. On the client side (so on your computer), you can use the ServerAliveInterval, which checks if the SSH server is still there and the connection open.

Answer (score 1):

You can not provide ServerAliveInterval in to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there is no support of ServerAliveInterval in sshd_config file instead provide ServerAliveInterval in client side (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).